# (Android) Dispatch "ENTER" key event to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm pretty new to Android development. I'm trying to detect spaces when they are typed into an `EditText` element and then instantly add a newline to the `EditText` element. Basically, trying to replace space keystrokes with the "enter" keystroke. I'm getting pretty close, as I've managed to detect 'spaces' when input into the EditText element, but upon detecting the space, I'm getting caught up on dispatching an "enter" key event into the `EditText` element. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm on the cusp of the answer, I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

```
public void addInputWordListener(){
    inputWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            sStr = s.toString();
            if(sStr.equals("")){
                topView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                return;
            }
            if (sStr.endsWith(" ")){    //space found!
                token = s.toString().trim();
                if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(topView.getText().toString())){
                    inputWord.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER); //doesnt work??
                    topView.setText(midView.getText());
                    midView.setText(botView.getText());
                    botView.setText(MainMenu.we.nextWord());
                    MainMenu.user.totalWords++;
                }else{
                    topView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    MainMenu.user.totalWords++;
                    MainMenu.user.numErrors++;
                }
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I should have definitely tried some basic Java stuff first before getting lost in Android's API ocean.
All it took was:

```
inputWord.append("\n");
```